# Poisson process, i.i.d exponential arrival times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

If $\{N(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, then the number of arrivals in $[0, t]$, called $N(t)$, is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda t$. Further, the inter-arrival times are exponential random variables with mean $ = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

I read that given the event that there is exactly one arrival in $[0, t]$, the arrival time $T$ is distributed uniformly on $[0, t]$ - conditioned on the event.

> Further, given the event that there are $k$ arrivals in $[0, t]$, the
> arrival times are distributed independently and uniformly in the
> interval $[0, t]$.

Suppose the arrival times are $T_1$, $T_2$, ..., $T_k$. How are they independent? For example, if I know $T_1 = \lambda$, I definitely know that $T_2$ must take values in $[\lambda, t]$. So $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not independent.

What is wrong with this interpretation?

Comment: More precisely conditional on $k$ events by time $t$, $N(t)=k$ then the arrival times are distributed as the order statistics of $k$ independent uniformly distributed numbers in $[0,t]$.

Comment: Your notation is misleading. $T_i$ is the arrival time of the event named $i$ (not number $i$!). In the "suppose" paragraph you treat them as the first event, second event and so on, in which case they are surely dependent because you don't ask about a specific event but the first event out of many.

Comment: @YJT that clarifies it for me.